# How to know whether two lines in 3D space are intersecting or not

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, 3d

While finding the distance between two lines, my book says that you will be asked for finding distance between skew lines or parallel lines, because intersecting lines would have this $0$.

But my question is how can I know whether the equation in front of me is of skew lines or intersecting lines ? (I can identify parallel lines)

Comment: Usually how do you represent lines in 3D space? Any example?

Comment: Write both the lines as intersection of two planes. Now they have a point in common if and only if the corresponding system of four linear equations in $x, y, z$ has solution, and you can check this by using the standard methods (e.g, the Rouché-Capelli theorem).

Comment: @RobertZ in vector form xi+yj+zk

Answer (score 1):

Two lines are skew if and only if they are not coplanar (they are not in a same plane). So take two distinct points on the first line and two distinct points on the second line and check if those four points are coplanar:
four points $P_i:=(x_i,y_i,z_i)$ for $i=1,2,3,4$ are coplanar  if and only if the vectors $P_2-P_1$, $P_3-P_1$, $P_4-P_1$  are linearly dependent that is if and only if the matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}x_2-x_1 & x_3-x_1 & x_4-x_1\\
y_2-y_1 & y_3-y_1 & y_4-x_1\\
z_2-z_1 & z_3-z_1 & z_4-z_1\end{bmatrix}$$
has determinant zero.

Comment: @Atul Mishra Are you able to detect skew lines now? Have you tried a few examples?

Comment: You mean “linearly dependent” in your last sentence, don’t you?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Yes! Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @RobertZ Sorry for the late response but I think you too are calculating distance between lines and checking if it is 0, because intersecting lines will have 0, I wanna know any other method,related to direction ratios, like product of direction ratios of two perpendicular lines is 0, direction ratios of parallel lines are proportional, etc....

Comment: @AtulMishra No, I am not calculating the distance between lines. The above determinant is a condition of coplanarity of four points. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coplanarity